# How can I restore my Windows File Explorer settings to original??? Why Metro apps do not work?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, resolution, windows-8-apps

Well I'm having a bad problem... My file explorer for Windows 8.1 Enterprise is damaged! whenever I try to open a new window it's always not maximized, I don't know why, even after I close and open again. I measured its resolution it was 1000*600, my normal PC resolution is 1600*900 laptop hp pavilion g7. I'll share the pics.
The second problem with file explorer that the view of the files inside any folder always changes by itself after I close, to View>Details. I change it but it keeps getting back.

And also my Metro apps do not work, I open any app it gets fast black screen then takes me to desktop, the app icon on taskbar is hidden!

I hope I find help here!

![Every window is not maximized, but when I start other thing like Chrome, it is maximized normally][1]

![The view inside any folder restores after I close the window][2]

![Metro apps never work][3]

http://postimg.org/image/mc6zfbu9b/
http://postimg.org/image/uswufe38v/

Answer (score 0):

If you think your windows installation is corrupted, you can try sfc /scannow

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/sfc-scannow.htm